# How to make the envelop html responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on the invite page, in which the envelope is shown first and after clicking on envelope it shows content, the problem is that the envelope is not responsive, I am using `display:flex` for my main page, but the template I used for envelope does not use flex, when I remove it, it works fine but my main page broke down, so is there any way to fix it?:
(the envelope looks like this on mobile screen)

[image: It look like this]

```css
.frame {
  width: 550px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  background: #435d77;
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
}

#button_open_envelope {
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 311;
  top: 250px;
  left: 208px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#button_open_envelope:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #2b67cb;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: background 0.25s, transform 0.5s, ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.message {
  position: relative;
  width: 580px;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #333;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 1.5s;
  z-index: 300;
}

.left,
.right,
.top {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 310;
}

.left {
  border-left: 300px solid #337efc;
  border-top: 160px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 160px solid transparent;
}

.right {
  border-right: 300px solid #337efc;
  border-top: 160px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 160px solid transparent;
  left: 300px;
}

.top {
  border-right: 300px solid transparent;
  border-top: 200px solid #03a9f4;
  border-left: 300px solid transparent;
  transition: transform 1s, border 1s, ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  z-index: 500;
}

.bottom {
  width: 600px;
  height: 190px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #2b67cb;
  top: 160px;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
  z-index: 310;
}

.open {
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.7s, border 0.7s, z-index 0.7s ease-in-out;
  border-top: 200px solid #2c3e50;
  z-index: 200;
}

.pull {
  -webkit-animation: message_animation 2s 1 ease-in-out;
  animation: message_animation 2s 1 ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
  animation-delay: 0.45s;
  transition: 1.5s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  z-index: 350;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* height: 100vh;
        width: 100%; */
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">

  <div id="button_open_envelope">
    Open Invitation
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <h1>Invitation</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: I can see in your css styles that you are specifying the sizes of the "left, bottom, top, right" section. Why don't you use also the media query is css like '@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)' so you can make it responsive manually?

Comment: Actually I am back-end dev, not familiar much with front-end, so confused what to do for make it responsive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `border` properties unfortunately don't take responsive percentages, so your `.top` `.left` and `.right` elements will not be responsive. You could instead create those envelope shapes with `clip-path` and then combined with a few other CSS updates and your envelope will adjust with screen size. Demo included

```css
.frame {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 550px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  background: #435d77;
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
}

#button_open_envelope {
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 311;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#button_open_envelope:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #2b67cb;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(1.1);
  transition: background 0.25s, transform 0.5s, ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.message {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #333;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 1.5s;
  z-index: 300;
}

.left,
.right,
.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 310;
}

.left {
  background: #337efc;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 90%, 50% 50%);
}

.right {
  background: #337efc;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 90%, 50% 50%);
}

.top {
  background: #03a9f4;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 62.5%);
  transition: transform 1s, border 1s, ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  z-index: 500;
}

.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2b67cb;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
  z-index: 310;
}

.open {
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.7s, border 0.7s, z-index 0.7s ease-in-out;
  border-top: 200px solid #2c3e50;
  z-index: 200;
}

.pull {
  -webkit-animation: message_animation 2s 1 ease-in-out;
  animation: message_animation 2s 1 ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
  animation-delay: 0.45s;
  transition: 1.5s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  z-index: 350;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div id="button_open_envelope">
    Open Invitation
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <h1>Invitation</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow! thanks exactly what I want, can you also tell me how add some padding when it view on mobile screen as currently it touchs to borders, I tried to add some padding but the shape of envelope changes?

Comment: NP! There are a few ways to keep it from touching the sides, but easiest way I can think is to adjust `.frame` width to something like `calc(100% - 30px)`